# Can we prove $\operatorname{tr}(M X X^T)$ is convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Define $f(X) = \operatorname{tr}(MXX^T)$. If $M$ is a positive semi-definite matrix, can we prove that $f$ is convex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
s\cdot f(X)+(1-s)\cdot f(Y)=f(sX+(1-s)Y)\color{red}{+s(1-s)\cdot f(X-Y)}
$$

Comment: And...what's next?

Comment: It's already over, for anybody knowing the meaning of the words in your question.

Comment: Er, yes, I understand from the above that f is convex, I just don't quite understand how we can get this equality...

Comment: $M(sX+(1-s)Y)(sX+(1-s)Y)^T=\ldots$ and the operator trace is linear hence $f(sX+(1-s)Y)=\ldots$